# Imagem está sendo cortada quando o elemento CSS "max-width" é usado

Tags: css3, layout-responsivo, redimensionamento

No rodapé [deste site Wordpress](https://domingodasorte.com.br/contato/) há várias imagens de logotipo.

> Estas imagens são inseridas pelo próprio usuário administrador do site
>   dentro de uma tabela [Pods](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/pods/), portanto eu não tenho controle individual
>   para cada imagem, apenas preciso aplicar um padrão para todas as
>   imagens.

As dimensões originais das imagens são muito diferentes, então eu preciso restringir seus tamanhos usando `max-width` e `max-height`, os quais eu coloquei na classe `wp-image-490`:

[image]

Mas ao fazer isso, se eu reduzo o tamanho da tela (para testar a responsividade), a primeira imagem está sendo cortada:

[image]

E ao mesmo tempo, tentei corrigir isto inserindo `width: 100%` nesta mesma classe, mas ao fazer isso, a segunda imagem fica distorcida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Coloca na tag da imagem object-fit: contain e object-position: 50% 50%; se resolver me fala que posto como resposta :)

Comment: Cara, tu é fera mesmo hein! Apenas inserindo "object-fit: contain" junto com o atual "width: 100%" já resolveu o problema. Pode colocar isso como resposta. Obrigado!

Comment: Tá respondido, valeu a força :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, esses problemas vc pode contorna limitando a imagem dentro do próprio container de renderização usando `object-fit: contain`. O que quero dize é que a imagem vai renderiza de forma que caiba proporcionalmente dentro do `width` e `height` que vc determinou.

Essa documentação vai te ajudar: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

E essa imagem vai ajudar vc a entender melhor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]